# 2d Array of objects not retaining values

Tags: java

I am a beginner android "developer" developing a chess app.

There is one variable in the `InGameActivity` class called `currentBoardState` which is `public static`. Every `ChessPiece` has a `boolean[][] possibleMoves`. This following method will take the `possibleMoves` and determine if any of the moves will cause the player to put him/herself in check and set it to false because it is no longer a possible move.

```
@Override
public void eliminateMovesThatPutYouInCheck() {
    ChessPiece[][] originalBoard = InGameActivity.currentBoardState;
    final ChessPiece emptyPiece = new EmptyPiece(Color.EMPTY);
    final ChessPiece tempKnight = new Knight(side);
    //This block eliminates moves that will cause a player
    //to put him/her self in check.
    InGameActivity.currentBoardState[x][y] = emptyPiece;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (possibleMoves[i][j] == true) {
                tempKnight.x = i;
                tempKnight.y = j;
                InGameActivity.currentBoardState[i][j] = tempKnight;
                if (InGameActivity.isPlayerInCheck(side)) {
                    possibleMoves[i][j] = false;
                }
                InGameActivity.currentBoardState[i][j] = emptyPiece;
            }
        }
    }
    InGameActivity.currentBoardState = originalBoard;
}
```

The problem is, my `currentBoardState` variable is being messed up and I dont know why, ive saved the value then reset it at the end of the method why is it losing its values?

EDIT: Here is the `isPlayerInCheck` method if you need it, thank you.

```
public static boolean isPlayerInCheck(Color side) {
        List<boolean[][]> opponentsMoves = new ArrayList<boolean[][]>();
        int xKing = -1;
        int yKing = -1;

        if (side.equals(Color.WHITE)) {
            xKing = whiteKing.x;
            yKing = whiteKing.y;
        } else {
            xKing = blackKing.x;
            yKing = blackKing.y;
        }

        if (side.equals(Color.WHITE)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (currentBoardState[i][j].isBlack()) {
                        opponentsMoves.add(currentBoardState[i][j].possibleMoves);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (boolean[][] b : opponentsMoves) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                        if (b[xKing][yKing] == true) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (currentBoardState[i][j].isWhite()) {
                        opponentsMoves.add(currentBoardState[i][j].possibleMoves);
                    }
                    if (currentBoardState[i][j].isBlack() && currentBoardState[i][j].getType().equals(Type.KING)) {
                        xKing = currentBoardState[i][j].x;
                        yKing = currentBoardState[i][j].y;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (boolean[][] b : opponentsMoves) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                        if (b[xKing][yKing] == true) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
    }
```

Also, I understand and appreciate that my code is probably very inefficient and the design is horrible for chess but that isn't really what I am concerned about at the moment.

Comment: OK, but what does it mean that "your `currentBoardState` variable is being **messed up**" !?

Comment: Do you mean its not resetting to the original board?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, my `currentBoardState` before the method, has `ChessPiece`s of type `King` `Queen` etc etc etc, but after I use the method, every cell is just a `ChessPiece` of type `Empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by `messed up` you mean the `currentBoardState` variable isn't being "reset" to the original board.

This is due to this line:

```
ChessPiece[][] originalBoard = InGameActivity.currentBoardState;
```

passing a **reference** of the current board state to the variable `originalBoard`.

As you make you modification to `currentBoardState`, since the `originalBoard` variable points to the same object, it gets modified as well.

Copy the array to the `originalBoard` variable like such:

```
ChessPiece[][] originalBoard = new ChessPiece[InGameActivity.currentBoardState.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < InGameActivity.currentBoardState.length; i++){
    ChessPiece[] pieces = InGameActivity.currentBoardState[i];
    int len = pieces.length;
    originalBoard[i] = new ChessPiece[len];
    System.arraycopy(pieces, 0, originalBoard[i], 0, len);
}

//Rest of code here...
```

Only when you copy by **value** does a actual copy of the data exist. Disregarding primitive types and some immutable data, using the assignment operator `=` merely assigns the reference of the RHS to the LHS.

Comment: I will try this now and get back to you. So this is what the whole "passing by reference" and "passing by value" thing is about...

Comment: @Clay Glad to help. I recommend you read up in depth on _pass by reference_ vs _pass by value_ since its a very fundamental concept in programming and will really screw you over if you don't take note of it. :)

Comment: I definitely will after spending this much time trying to figure out what was going on >_< Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, I think you need to copy the original to a new array, for example:

```
ChessPiece[][] originalBoard = Arrays.copyOf(
    InGameActivity.currentBoardState, InGameActivity.currentBoardState.length);
```

This prevents modification of the original array.

Comment: Is this not the equivalent of just using the `=` operator?

Comment: No. Using = will copy the array reference, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem here:

```
if (possibleMoves[i][j]) 
{ 
    tempKnight.x = i;
    tempKnight.y = j;
    InGameActivity.currentBoardState[i][j] = tempKnight;
    if (InGameActivity.isPlayerInCheck(side))
    {
       possibleMoves[i][j] = false;
    }
    /** whatever was before next line resets the value at i,j: puts empty piece here */
    InGameActivity.currentBoardState[i][j] = emptyPiece;
}
```